# Instagram follower list API for other users

Tags: c#, .net, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to fetch the follower list of a specific user using C#.

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiEndPoint))
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            string responseJSON = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I have added a couple of users in Instagram's Sandbox and all the scope permissions during authorization. I am able to get the following list **for self** using the below API-

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=****

But I can't do it for other users. Earlier there was an API for this under-

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/

Now it seems Instagram has revoked this feature recently. Is there any other way I can do this?

Please let me know if I can provide some more details or clarifications.

Comment: When you get your access token, are you setting the scope to follower_list?

Comment: @Rogala Yes I did. Infact I have set all the scope parameters

Comment: So I know Facebook modified their endpoint a while back, where they locked down the friends API so that only friends who signed up for an app would appear.  Maybe Instagram did the same thing.  Did you look at their release notes?  When functionality is deprecated, the APIs are well documented in advance.

Comment: @Rogala I think it's clear that they have removed it as it's nowhere there in the Endpoints section in their website. Also few other posts across SO suggests they are removed. However, there is a third party API (https://www.magimetrics.com) which still fetches them and generates a CSV file. I am just confused how they are still doing it if the API is removed.

Comment: Some time they grandfather previous apps in so that they are still available.  The other possibility is that magimetrics has enough users and enough data to do their own correlation on their using their datasets.  I had this happen to me with the Facebook API and I know your frustration.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/

Instagram will deprecate API that reads user's follower list.